# Add border to custom marker image on google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, border, marker

I am using markers for showing my GPS data on Google map.
The js code for this is as following:

```
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);
var mapOptions = {
  zoom: 4,
  center: myLatlng
}

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);
var imagePath = "somePath\abc.jpg";
var markerImg = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
    imagePath,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    new google.maps.Size(32, 32)
);

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: myLatlng,
  icon: markerImg,
  map: map
});
```

Markers render fine as images on the map. My marker images are dynamic for some reason and upon rendering I need to draw a white border of 2px around their HTML element. But I am finding no way of doing this.

Can any one please tell which way I can do that ?

Comment: Did you try with `marker.setIcon(new-icon-object-specs)`?

Comment: Anto, can you explain your query ?

Comment: If you are asking about Icon object specs, yes I studied that but it gives no option to customize the resulting HTML element of image.

Comment: I misunderstood that. I thought that you just wanted to apply changed icons. Thanks.